# Magento : Home Page New Products Add to Cart Button Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, product, addtocart

On my website home page, I added new products using block in that add to cart button is not adding products to cart **only the first time when I clear the cache** but if I open the site in a new browser and add to cart I get the (shopping cart is empty) page, which is very strange.

Here is the code for `new.phtml`

```
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
<div class="page-title category-title">
        <h1><?php echo $this->__('New Products') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul class="products-grid row">
        <?php endif ?>
            <li class="item span3<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <div class="extra-block">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(170) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                </div>

                    <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></h3>
                    <p class="desc_grid"><?php $small_getDescription = strip_tags($_product->getShortDescription());
         if (strlen($small_getDescription) < 80) echo($small_getDescription);
         else { echo substr($small_getDescription, 0, 60).'...';} ?></p> 
         <?php // echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ?>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                    <div class="product-shop">

                  <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?> ')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('COMING SOON') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                <?php /*
                    <div class="actions">


                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if ($_compareUrl = $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul> 
                    </div> 
                    */?>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==count($_products)): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with new security added in magento 1.9 and form_key that is added to add to cart buttons and will not cache the New Products Block. Put cache_lifetime="1" at the end of the calling block in CMS page, this will disable the caching for the new products

```
<action method="setCacheLifetime">
        <lifetime>1</lifetime> 
    </action>
```

or

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" column_count="6" products_count="12" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" cache_lifetime="1"}}
```